# Fine sheaf and exact form

Tags: differential-geometry, sheaf-theory, sheaf-cohomology

[image]

I can't see why since $\xi$ is an element of $Z^2(U,\epsilon)$ and $\epsilon$ is fine, there exists a $\tau\in C^1(U,\epsilon)$ so that $\delta\tau=\xi$.

Comment: Can you please tell the book from which this theorem was taken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fine sheaves have no higher cohomology, so any $k$-cocycle is a $k$-coboundary for $k\ge 1$.